# HTML1506: Unexpected token, with stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

I am trying to upgrade a series of gems so that I can get current support.  However, whenever I try this, I start receiving HTML1506 on applications.html.erb.  The problem occurs between stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag where a "/body" is followed by a "script".  Both are generated, so I can't seem to resolve the issue.

The gems I am upgrading include:

```
Successfully installed sprockets-3.4.0
Successfully installed sprockets-rails-2.3.3
Successfully installed sass-rails-5.0.4
Successfully installed bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.1
Successfully installed jquery-rails-4.0.5
```

The error I get is:

From better-errors:

```
Invalid CSS after "...les.responsive'": expected "{", was ";"
```

From F12 console:

```
HTML1506: Unexpected token.
```

From F12 debugger:

```
</section>
</body>
<script>
(function() {
```

I understand that  after  is syntactically incorrect.  However, I am generating neither of them!

applications.html.erb is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="me-at-gmail.com">
  <link href="<%= image_path("item.ico") %>" rel="icon" type="image/png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Default title..." %></title>
  <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Key and Car Tracking" %>">
  <%= puts "Action#Controller is " + @_request.filtered_parameters['action'] + "#" + @_request.filtered_parameters['controller'] %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js", "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <% csrf_meta_tags %>
  <% #render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
  For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript.
  Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
  instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
</noscript>
<header>
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
</header>
<main role="main">
  <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h5 style='color: #97b3fc'>Beta Test version.  Not for production. Copyright 2015&copy;</h5>
  <a rel="license" class='hidden' href="http://www.example.com/">Copyrighted 2015</a>
</main>
<%= debug(get_route_pattern) if Rails.env.development? %>
<%= debug(request.class) if Rails.env.development? %>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given that the error is 'invalid css' and you say it happens during stylesheet tag, it may be useful to show your stylesheet,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yule's tip helped me find the error.  Strangely enough, I assumed the stylesheet was valid because it worked before the upgrade.  There was a typo in it that was causing the problem when I commented out some code, as follows:

```
/*
@import 'core';
@import 'datepicker';  /* comments */
@import 'theme';       /* comments */
*/
```

The problem was that the very first */, following the comment on the datepicker line, terminated the top /*.  This caused the final */ to be invalid and throwing the error.

This seems to be an obvious problem in SCSS preprocessing as it should catch such an error and provide a less cryptic error message.  However, in any case, problem solved for now.  Thanks Yule.